# Changing the url address with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following URL structure:
www.foo.com/products/first/

I want to change the text that comes right after products.

My HTML looks like that (Just to give you the main idea)

```
<section data-product="first">
..content..
</section>

<section data-product="second">
..content..
</section>

<section data-product="third">
..content..
</section>
```

Each section has a height of 100% of the window, so whenever the user scrolls until the head of a section, I want the URL address to change accordingly.

I achieved everything but the URL address change to that specific area in the string.

Comment: I am not trying to refresh the page ..

Answer (score 0):

By all means manipulate the location hash using `window.location.hash` but please don't try to modify the page URL itself.

Comment: I can't have the page refreshed, I want the user to be able to scroll between the products without entering the page over and over again